# Equivalent of parse.com for Adobe AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, webserver, parse-platform

I'm currently working on a game project in Obj-c/iOS. I'm a AS3/Flash dev though so I was wondering if it's possible for me to do the game in Adobe AIR. The issue is saving the games/player details to the server, getting them back etc. Parse.com is great at this, but I was wondering if there's an equivalent to use with Adobe AIR? I know there's a AS3 REST API for using parse, but that doesn't seem as straight forward to use as the parse iOS SDK.

Answer (score 1):

We use playerio for saving our game data.

Answer (score 0):

someone created a new AS3 parse API, https://github.com/camdagr8/AS3-Parse-Class/blob/master/com/illumifi/Parse.as (i have forgot where did i get this link, so i link you to the github),
to use it, you must change line 17 and 18, and add this line of code to the import part to make the code works

```
import flash.net.URLVariables;
```

the author forgot to import it

for the SignUp, if you want to use

`Parse.SignUp(username,password,....)`

change line 108 - 110 to

```
public static function SignUp(username:String, password:String, success:Function = null, error:Function = null):void {
    var params:Object = {username: username, password: password};
    Parse.User.Post(params, success, error);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be interesting in that http://parse-ane.launchrock.co/ Adobe air native extension for parse

Answer (score 0):

district just released parse ane for both android and iOS

http://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.Parse

p.s. I am not affiliated with them